# Comparar duas colunas no EXCEL e se forem iguais retornar um determinado valor

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, office-2013

Estou com dificuldades para gerar uma estrutura lógica (If) para validar alguns dados. É para uma pesquisa. segue a explicação:

- Há duas colunas (**B** e **H**). Na coluna **B** há todos os municípios brasileiros e na coluna H não há todos (mas a maioria).
  [image: Geral]
- A coluna **I** contém as notas obtidas pelos municípios da coluna **H**
- A coluna **C** deverá receber todos os dados da coluna **I** em seus respectivos municípios
- Como na coluna **B** há mais municípios que na coluna **H** (conforme anteriormente citado) eu estou tentando criar uma regra em VBA que compare a coluna **B** com a **H**, se os municípios comparados forem iguais, o dado da coluna **I** passará para a coluna **C** em seu respectivo municipio
- Ex: Compara B2 com H2, se forem iguais, C2 recebe I2.
- Tentei fazer em VBA mas como não consegui chegar nem perto do objetivo, não considero necessário postar o código (que está bagunçado e não comentado). Se alguém souber uma forma de fazer sem ser por VBA, sem problemas, o importante para mim é o resultado.
- Foto da expectativa de como deve ficar:
  [image: Expectativa, resultado]

**OBS:** 
Os municipios em vermelhos na coluna **B** são os que não estão **H**

As colunas **D** e **E** podem ser desconsideradas, eu entendendo como faz para uma já conseguirei fazer para elas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso não precisa fazer em VBA, pode usar o `PROCV` da seguinte forma:

Na célula `C2`:

```
=PROCV($A2;$H$2:$I$6000;2;FALSO)
```

No exemplo acima coloquei como tendo em torno de 6.000 municípios, mas veja a quantidade de linhas que tem em sua planilha.

Para complementar poderia usar a seguinte fórmula para aparecer o `n/a` conforme citado em sua pergunta:

```
=SE(ÉERROS(PROCV($A2;$H$2:$I$6000;2;FALSO));"n/a";PROCV($A2;$H$2:$I$6000;2;FALSO))
```

Espero ter ajudado!